# Prolog Get the differences in days between two dates

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I've been trying to compare 2 dates in prolog.

The dates format is date(YYYY, MM, DD)

ex: (2016,04,21).

I want to compare two dates and know if the difference (in days) between those dates is bigger than 15 days (2 weeks).

```
%dateDifference( number_of_day, date_no1, date_no2 ).
dateDifference( 35, date(2003,8,16), date(2003,9,20) ).
```

Comment: You say, "I've been trying". You should show what you tried and explain why it didn't work and where you are stuck.

Comment: Check [**library(julian)**](https://github.com/mndrix/julian) by Michael Hendricks for a very elegant and general way to reason about dates in Prolog.

Comment: @mat when I try adding this pack(PDT-SWI)  I have this error : `ERROR: [Thread pdt_console_client_0_Default Process] make_directory/1: No permission to create directory c:/program files/swipl/pack'' (Permission denied)` also it's not work in sisctus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing the difference in days between two dates can be simple or tricky depending on the calendar and on the covered periods. Assuming the Gregorian calendar, the common solution is to convert the dates to Julian days. As @mat mentioned in its comment, for SWI-Prolog, consider the `library(julian)`;

https://github.com/mndrix/julian

For a portable solution that can be used with most Prolog systems (including SWI-Prolog), Logtalk includes a third-party ISO 8601 library that can be used for these computations:

http://logtalk.org/library/iso8601_0.html

Answer (score 0):

first off, you should put account the note of @Boris, 
second,
in order to simplify the issue, your predicate divided into three parts:

part 1:

- know if year is leap or common,
- affect the number of days for each month,
- Finally this part follow the following rule;

code :

```
calcule_days([Y,M,D],Res):-
    Res is (((Y*1461)/4)+((M*153)/5)+D).
```

part 2 :

- calculates the difference between the two dates so
- apply the `formula` (part1) with date1 and date2,
- calculate the differences between the two results `difference_date1_date2` ,
- to avoid the negative sign add `abs(difference_date1_date2)`
- to obtain a value added approach `round (result_abs_pred)`

demo code :

```
dateDifference(NumberOfDays,date(YEAR1,MONTH1,DAY1),date(YEAR2,MONTH2,DAY2)):-
           ...
```

part3:

- testing whether the result is `>= 15`, result must be `True/false`

demo code :

```
bigger_2weeks(date(YEAR1,MONTH1,DAY1),date(YEAR2,MONTH2,DAY2)):-
...
```

Comment: The straight-forward way to do that would be to convert the two  `date(Year, Month, Day)` to seconds since a given point in time using a proper library, as per usual, then get the difference and turn this into days or weeks or whatever.

Comment: @Boris, I try to add library(julian)  but I can't with both sisctus SP and swi-PDT

Comment: You don't need library(julian), at least for SWI-Prolog: there is a [library that deals with dates](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=timedate).